# Laravel with Amazon AWS SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel-5.1, amazon-sqs

I've changed the queue driver over to AWS SQS in a Laravel 5.1 project, but now whenever the queue is called I get...

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Aws\Common\Client\AbstractClient::__construct() must be an instance of
>   Aws\Common\Credentials\CredentialsInterface, array given, called in
>   /home/vagrant/Code/ukisug/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Connectors/SqsConnector.php
>   on line 26

Any ideas?

Comment: can you added little more details, and also add in question, which configuration you are using and which SQS method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the sdk version.

For example in composer the latest stable version worked for me:

```
"aws/aws-sdk-php":"3.17.3"
```

I'm using

```
"symfony/symfony": "3.0.*",
"knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle": "~0.3",
```

but it seems it has nothing to do with the setup, but with the sdk.